# PostgreSQL: SET statement from a variable

Tags: postgresql

In general I found the treatment of variables in Postgres much confusing compared to typical programming languages, and then I came to this one:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
    x INTEGER;
BEGIN
    x := 5; -- imagine doing some involved query to get to this value
    RAISE NOTICE 'x is %', x;
    SET app.foo = x;
    RAISE NOTICE 'app.foo is %', (SELECT current_setting('app.foo'));
END;
$$;
```

Much to my surprise, `app.foo is x` gets printed, where I expected `app.foo is 5`. From there I arrive to the conclusion that the right hand side of the SET statement is not evaluated, and it has to be constant. Is this how it's supposed to be?

Is there any way to assign a result of a query into a configuration parameter?

Context: I'm using `current_setting` for row level security ala https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/how-implement-column-and-row-level-security-postgresql

Comment: Use `set_config()` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `EXECUTE`:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    x INTEGER;
BEGIN
    x := 5; -- imagine doing some involved query to get to this value
    RAISE NOTICE 'x is %', x;
    EXECUTE 'SET app.foo =' || x::text;
    RAISE NOTICE 'app.foo is %', (SELECT current_setting('app.foo'));
END;
$$;

NOTICE:  x is 5
NOTICE:  app.foo is 5
DO
```

For more information see [Execute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). In particular:

> Another restriction on parameter symbols is that they only work in SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE commands. In other statement types (generically called utility statements), you must insert values textually even if they are just data values.